# how to scale an existing pdf margins using Itext

Tags: java, itext

Could any one please help with how we could do the following steps using an itext library?

1) Read an existing pdf

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Letter.pdf");

    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
```

2)using stamper,I am able to copy the (src) exact page onto a different pdf (Result). But for say, if the src pdf has a certain margins like, (36, 72, 36, 36) left, right, top and bottom margins, and if I want to move them all margins to (0, 0, 0, 0)? How can I produce a Resulting Pdf with those margins?
I have examples in itext to set margins for a new document but I dont know how to do this with exisiting pdf and its content.. example: ResizeMargins

```
    Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
        document.setMargins(36, 72, 36, 36);
        document.setMarginMirroring(true);
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(new Paragraph(
            "The left margin of this odd page is 36pt (0.5 inch); " +
            "the right margin 72pt (1 inch); " +
            "the top margin 108pt (1.5 inch); " +
            "the bottom margin 180pt (2.5 inch)."));
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            paragraph.add("Hello World! Hello People! " +
                    "Hello Sky! Hello Sun! Hello Moon! Hello Stars!");
        }
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.add(new Paragraph(
            "The right margin of this even page is 36pt (0.5 inch); " +
            "the left margin 72pt (1 inch)."));
        // step 5
        document.close();
```

could anyone please help

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You can change the page boundaries of an existing document (such as the MediaBox and the CropBox), but what you do in step 3 is totally wrong. It isn't clear at all what you mean by "scale an existing PDF margins". You'll have to put more effort into your question and explain in more detail what the original PDF looks like and how you want the new PDF to look like. People reading your question can't know what you mean based on the incomplete information you're providing.

Comment: sorry, I will change the content.thank you for your input.